# regex to replace javascript content using powershell script

Tags: javascript, regex, powershell

I am using powershell script to replace some content of the text which is in a javascript file

```
 var i = {
        production: !0,
        myBaseURL: "https://www.sample.com/api/",
       }

 (Get-Content -literalPath $pathToJsFile -raw) -replace "https://www.sample.com", 
  "https://www.newserver.com"|

    Out-File $jspath -encoding UTF8
```

I want to replace this using regex as it can be anything instead of "https://www.sample.com"
I tried

```
 $file -replace "myBaseURL\s*: .*", "myBaseURL: $([char]34)https://www.newserver.com([char]34),"
```

is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: [Don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/542251)

Comment: @Reinstate Monica Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad idea. Instead of replacing, consider generating a JS file with the attributes, and including it earlier than your code in the DOM.

Alternatively use your domain name to decide which environment you are in.

```
var env;
switch(window.location.hostname){
  case "example.com": 
    env = "prod"; 
  case "dev.example.com":
    env = "dev";
```